# Pre-SDF gazebo XML documentation?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Is there any documentation of what I assume is the pre-SDF 1.0 Gazebo XML configuration format? The one with XML namespaces like `xmlns:controller="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#controller"` and so on.

I have some old models that I need to understand and update that use this format.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/276/pre-sdf-gazebo-xml-documentation?/) by [mjog](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/97/mjog/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-11-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I believe that documentation has long since disappeared.

I think gazebo version 1.0 may have been able to convert from the old format to SDF.

Alternatively, you can grab an old version of gazebo from bitbucket and inspect the code.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2012-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0